# Split JSON into several XML messages

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I'm running Mule CE 3.8 and I have a huge JSON looking something like this:

```
{
"Balances": [
    {
        "Amount": 0,
        "Id": "003100010003",
        "Location": 101,

    },
    {
        "Amount": 10,
        "Id": "003100010003",
        "Location": "106"
    },
```

I need to split this file into XML messages as soon as I reach 1000 records.
Every XML Headersection need to have a field that says how many messages there are in total and which number the current XML Message is.
I read about splitter / aggregator and it seem to be able to handle these things, but I'm not sure how to approach it.

Do I split my balances on every 1000th record somehow, or do I split on every single balance record and handle the counting on the agggregator to generate a new XML Message for every 1000th record?
Can I use the MULE variables MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE and MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE to set my XML Header info fields on every single XML messages somehow?

Or am I guessing very badly?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can use foreach scope where you can provide payload count.

HTH

Comment: Forgot about Foreach, seem to be able to handle it, better read up on that one

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1. Collection splitter with a counter variable
2. Write a small Java component to access this payload and iterate over the payload as you need

Comment: Thanks for answering.. I've only written custom transformers so far but you mean that I could write a java component that very 1000th record create an XML message and dispatch it? I guess I'll need to read up on how to do that, don't know how to create messages like that

Answer (score 0):

Use a batch commit with a size of 100 and use json to xml transformer